# Insert rows to fill sequence

Tags: sql

I am attempting to insert rows where I missing years in the Year column. The idea is to have a year and value populated for every year up until 2016, starting with the first year for a given id. Here is my current state:

```
id  year    value
a   2016    100
a   2015    90
a   2007    60
b   2016    120
b   2014    105
c   2015    110
c   2014    90
d   2016    150
```

Here is my desired state:

```
id  year    value
a   2016    100
a   2015    90
a   2014    60
a   2013    60
a   2012    60
a   2011    60
a   2010    60
a   2009    60
a   2008    60
a   2007    60
b   2016    120
b   2015    105
b   2014    105
c   2016    110
c   2015    110
c   2014    90
d   2016    150
```

So, populate missing years with the value from the previous year. How can this be achieved in Excel, SQL or VBA? I can throw this into an access database to get the job done. The only thing I can think of right now is joining my current table to a table in SQL with all the years I want and then go through a repopulate the NULL values. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit: How do I do this specifically using SQL?**

Comment: `value populated for every year up until 2016` from when ? and also explain the logic

Comment: Your idea to use SQL to do this is good. If you have a quick way to get this into a database and do that, then I would go that route. VBA is going to be a little painful compared to a quick SQL statement.

Comment: Also, your example data shows that the first year for `a` is `2015` with a value `90` but your desired results show dates going back to `2007` for `a` with an unexplained value of `60`.

Comment: Data updated. I missed putting a - 2007 - 60 in the current state. Does that make more sense @JNevill

Comment: @TheGameiswar from the first year I have for that id. So for id a it's 2007, b 2014, c 1014 and d is 2016

Comment: Do you need the SQL for MS Access or for a different DBMS?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Access would be ideal but anything would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with VBA, brute force method shown below.
Please let me know if you have any questions.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
' assuming data is always sorted by id
Dim Row As Integer
Dim curID, prevID As String
Dim curYr, prevYr As Integer
Dim prevVal As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Row = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
' This does 2 things gets the prevID and makes sure previous line selects the actual last row
prevID = ""
Do
   prevID = ws.Cells(Row, 1)
   prevYr = ws.Cells(Row, 2)
   prevVal = ws.Cells(Row, 3)
   Row = Row - 1
Loop Until prevID <> "" Or Row = 2

While Row > 2
   curID = ws.Cells(Row, 1)
   curYr = ws.Cells(Row, 2)

   ' next id
   If curID <> prevID Then
      Row = Row + 1
      For i = 2016 To (prevYr + 1) Step -1
         ws.Rows(Row).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
         ws.Cells(Row, 1) = prevID
         ws.Cells(Row, 2) = i
         ws.Cells(Row, 3) = prevVal
      Next i
      Row = Row - 1
      prevID = curID
      prevYr = curYr
      prevVal = ws.Cells(Row, 3)
   ' next year
   ElseIf curYr - 1 = prevYr Then
      prevID = curID
      prevYr = curYr
      prevVal = ws.Cells(Row, 3)
   ' in between
   Else
      Row = Row + 1
      For i = (prevYr + 1) To (curYr - 1)
         ws.Rows(Row).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
         ws.Cells(Row, 1) = prevID
         ws.Cells(Row, 2) = i
         ws.Cells(Row, 3) = prevVal
      Next i
      If prevYr = curYr Then
         Row = Row - 1
      End If
      prevYr = curYr
   End If

   Row = Row - 1
Wend
```